# fstab does not mount cifs at startup

Tags: shell, centos, samba, fstab, cifs

I'm using Cent OS 6.5. I have a cifs share which needs to be automatically mounted at the system reboot/startup.

Following is the line from my `/etc/fstab` file :

```
//192.168.1.2/files/ /users/ cifs _netdev,credentials=/root/secret.txt,uid=apache,gid=apache 0 0
```

When I run `mount -a` command the cifs mounts into the system, but does not automatically mount when I reboot or startup the machine.

Any reasons for this?

EDIT:
When I `cat /var/log/messages | grep -i cifs` I get the following logs

```
Apr 21 17:01:13 cloud kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -113
Apr 21 17:03:32 cloud kernel: CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation
Apr 21 17:03:32 cloud kernel: CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -113
Apr 21 17:03:32 cloud kernel: CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation
```

Comment: If you use `grep -i cifs` instead of `grep cifs`, do you see any additional error messages? Do you see `CIFS VFS: Error connecting to IPv4 socket. Aborting operation`?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes I'm getting an error like that. I have updated it on my question.

Answer (score 2):

http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2012-0816.html

It seems the `netfs` service should do what you want since 6.3

So propably you should just enable it on boot.

http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares#head-64eaf1fbf783896908fc01021bdba240c2c4ff0b

Describes what you have done as 3.

But: netfs in CentOS does not mout as Fedora does...

to be continued...

Comment: I enabled it. But still no use - http://i.imgur.com/MPAYTka.png

Comment: @chmzzy Interesting. Do umount cifs and do `sh -x /etc/init.d/netfs start`. Perhaps you can see what is going wrong there.

Comment: Here is what I got when I ran your command (I have no idea what it says, It would be great if you could explain me) - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HbAm1BTW

Comment: @chmzzy The init-script parses your fstab, finds a _netdev entry without noauto, sees that this should be cifs and assigns some varables. Then it activates your cloud vg with its three LVs. But then there is no mount command. Strange. Can you upload the init-script into pastebin, too? I have no co6 in reach at the moment.

Comment: Which init-script do you want? Here is rc.sysinit http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DXAaMaxB Hope this will be useful

Comment: @chmzzy please upload /etc/init.d/netfs

Comment: Here's /etc/init.d/netfs : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=q2fXAFfL

Comment: @chmzzy Interesting. This is a big diff compared to Fedora Core. There is no mount-command in CO.

Comment: Any updated on this?

Comment: @chmzzy I set up a co6-vm to get into this. Looks like a real bug to me. I will update my answer later on.